# Database lock sqlite flutter

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, dart, transactions

I don't really know where the problem is... can someone tell me what should i do to solve the database lock?

this is my sqlite code

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static DatabaseHelper? _databaseHelper;
  static Database? _database;

  DatabaseHelper._internal() {
    _databaseHelper = this;
  }

  factory DatabaseHelper() {
    _databaseHelper ??= DatabaseHelper._internal();
    return _databaseHelper!;
  }

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    _database = await _initializeDB();
    return _database;
  }

  final String _tableAndung = 'job_andung';
  final String _tableImran = 'job_imran';
  final String _tableAksa = 'job_aksa';

  Future<Database> _initializeDB() async {
    var db = await openDatabase(
      join(
        await getDatabasesPath(),
        'multimedia_job.db', // Mengganti nama database
      ),
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        // Pembuatan tabel data kak Andung
        await db.execute(
          '''CREATE TABLE $_tableAndung(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            date TEXT,
            fb INTEGER,
            yt INTEGER,
            shorts INTEGER,
            ig INTEGER,
            tiktok INTEGER,
            total INTEGER,
            targetFb INTEGER,
            targetYt INTEGER,
            targetShorts INTEGER,
            targetIg INTEGER,
            targetTiktok INTEGER,
            targetTotal INTEGER)''',
        );
        // Pembuatan tabel data kak Imran
        await db.execute(
          '''CREATE TABLE $_tableImran(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            date TEXT,
            fb INTEGER,
            yt INTEGER,
            shorts INTEGER,
            ig INTEGER,
            tiktok INTEGER,
            total INTEGER,
            targetFb INTEGER,
            targetYt INTEGER,
            targetShorts INTEGER,
            targetIg INTEGER,
            targetTiktok INTEGER,
            targetTotal INTEGER)''',
        );

        // Pembuatan tabel data kak Aksa
        await db.execute(
          '''CREATE TABLE $_tableAksa(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            date TEXT,
            fb INTEGER,
            yt INTEGER,
            shorts INTEGER,
            ig INTEGER,
            tiktok INTEGER,
            total INTEGER,
            targetFb INTEGER,
            targetYt INTEGER,
            targetShorts INTEGER,
            targetIg INTEGER,
            targetTiktok INTEGER,
            targetTotal INTEGER)''',
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
    return db;
  }

  //Mengambil data Kak Andung
  Future<List<AndungJobModels>> getListAndung() async {
    final db = await database;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];

    await db!.transaction((txn) async {
      results = await txn.query(_tableAndung);
    });

    return results
        .map(
          (e) => AndungJobModels.fromMap(e),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  // Mengambil data Kak Imran
  Future<List<ImranJobModels>> getListImran() async {
    final db = await database;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];

    await db!.transaction((txn) async {
      results = await txn.query(_tableImran);
    });

    return results
        .map(
          (e) => ImranJobModels.fromMap(e),
        )
        .toList();
  }

// Mengambil data Kak Aksa
  Future<List<AksaJobModels>> getListAksa() async {
    final db = await database;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];

    await db!.transaction((txn) async {
      results = await txn.query(_tableAksa);
    });

    return results
        .map(
          (e) => AksaJobModels.fromMap(e),
        )
        .toList();
  }

//Menambahkan data kak Andung kedalam tabel
  Future<void> insertJobAndung(AndungJobModels dataModel) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.insert(
          _tableAndung,
          dataModel.toMap(),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> insertJobImran(ImranJobModels dataModel) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.insert(
          _tableImran,
          dataModel.toMap(),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> insertJobAksa(AksaJobModels dataModel) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.insert(
          _tableAksa,
          dataModel.toMap(),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> removeAndungJob(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.delete(
          _tableAndung,
          where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [id],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> removeImranJob(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.delete(
          _tableImran,
          where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [id],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> removeAksaJob(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.delete(
          _tableAksa,
          where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [id],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> updateAndungJob(
      int id, Map<String, dynamic> updatedValues) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.update(
          _tableAndung,
          updatedValues,
          where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [id],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> updateImranJob(
      int id, Map<String, dynamic> updatedValues) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.update(
          _tableImran,
          updatedValues,
          where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [id],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> updateAksaJob(int id, Map<String, dynamic> updatedValues) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db!.transaction(
      (txn) async {
        await txn.update(
          _tableAksa,
          updatedValues,
          where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [id],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is the models

```
class AndungJobModels with ChangeNotifier {
  int? id;
  int? fb;
  int? yt;
  int? shorts;
  int? ig;
  int? tiktok;
  int? total;
  int? targetFb;
  int? targetYt;
  int? targetShorts;
  int? targetIg;
  int? targetTiktok;
  int? targetTotal;
  String? date;

  AndungJobModels({
    this.id,
    this.fb = 0,
    this.yt = 0,
    this.shorts = 0,
    this.ig = 0,
    this.tiktok = 0,
    this.total = 0,
    this.targetFb = 0,
    this.targetYt = 0,
    this.targetShorts = 0,
    this.targetIg = 0,
    this.targetTiktok = 0,
    this.targetTotal = 0,
    this.date,
  }) {
    hitungTotal();
  }

  void hitungTotal() {
    total = (fb ?? 0) + (yt ?? 0) + (shorts ?? 0) + (ig ?? 0) + (tiktok ?? 0);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  factory AndungJobModels.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => AndungJobModels(
        id: map['id'],
        fb: map['fb'],
        targetFb: map['targetFb'],
        yt: map['yt'],
        targetYt: map['targetYt'],
        shorts: map['shorts'],
        targetShorts: map['targetShorts'],
        ig: map['ig'],
        targetIg: map['targetIg'],
        tiktok: map['tiktok'],
        targetTiktok: map['targetTiktok'],
        total: map['total'],
        targetTotal: map['targetTotal'],
        date: map['date'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'id': id,
        'fb': fb,
        'targetFb': targetFb,
        'yt': yt,
        'targetYt': targetYt,
        'shorts': shorts,
        'targetShorts': targetShorts,
        'ig': ig,
        'targetIg': targetIg,
        'tiktok': tiktok,
        'targetTiktok': targetTiktok,
        'total': total,
        'targetTotal': targetTotal,
        'date': date,
      };
}
```

and this is the code that i add and make the database lock happend

```
class RekapAndung extends StatelessWidget {
  const RekapAndung({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int totalFbAndung = 0;
    int totalYtAndung = 0;
    int totalShortsAndung = 0;
    int totalIgAndung = 0;
    int totalTiktokAndung = 0;
    int totalAkhir = 0;
    final andungProvider = Provider.of<AndungJobProvider>(context);
    return FutureBuilder<List<AndungJobModels>>(
      future: andungProvider.loadAndungData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        var dataAndung = snapshot.data;
        if (dataAndung != null) {
          for (int i = 0; i < dataAndung.length; i++) {
            totalFbAndung += dataAndung[i].fb ?? 0;
            totalYtAndung += dataAndung[i].yt ?? 0;
            totalShortsAndung += dataAndung[i].shorts ?? 0;
            totalIgAndung += dataAndung[i].ig ?? 0;
            totalTiktokAndung += dataAndung[i].tiktok ?? 0;
          }
        }
        totalAkhir = totalFbAndung +
            totalYtAndung +
            totalShortsAndung +
            totalIgAndung +
            totalTiktokAndung;
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    offset: const Offset(0, 0),
                    color:
                        Color.fromARGB(0.25.toInt(), 0, 0, 0).withOpacity(0.2),
                    blurRadius: 1,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  if (dataAndung != null && dataAndung.isNotEmpty)
                    RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                dataAndung[0].date ?? "Tanggal Belumm Dipilih",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: dataAndung[0].date == null
                                  ? Colors.red
                                  : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const TextSpan(
                            text: "\nhingga\n",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Color(0xFF1570EF),
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: dataAndung[dataAndung.length - 1].date ??
                                "Tanggal Belum Dipilih!",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color:
                                  dataAndung[dataAndung.length - 1].date == null
                                      ? Colors.red
                                      : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  const Divider(thickness: 1.5),
                  SosmedWidget(
                    type: "Row",
                    sosmed: "Facebook",
                    imagePath: 'assets/images/fb.png',
                    value: totalFbAndung,
                  ),
                  SosmedWidget(
                    type: "Row",
                    sosmed: "Youtube",
                    imagePath: 'assets/images/yt.png',
                    value: totalYtAndung,
                  ),
                  SosmedWidget(
                    type: "Row",
                    sosmed: "Shorts",
                    imagePath: 'assets/images/shorts.png',
                    value: totalShortsAndung,
                  ),
                  SosmedWidget(
                    type: "Row",
                    sosmed: "Instagram",
                    imagePath: 'assets/images/ig.png',
                    value: totalIgAndung,
                  ),
                  SosmedWidget(
                    type: "Row",
                    sosmed: "TikTok",
                    imagePath: 'assets/images/tiktok.png',
                    value: totalTiktokAndung,
                  ),
                  const Divider(thickness: 1.5),
                  const Text(
                    "Total",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 22,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "$totalAkhir",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 22,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

debug console

```
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 12 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 1223 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 47 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 817 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 796 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 19 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 68 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 12 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 236 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
I/chatty  ( 6072): uid=10278(com.example.fajar_app) 1.ui identical 572 lines
2
I/flutter ( 6072): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
Lost connection to device.
```

how to fix the lock database issue if the code like up above? i think the problem is in RekapAndung Class because before i add this class all code are work properly

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning. You are doing a huge amount of SQL queries. You can use `batch` which can help you.

```
batch = db.batch();
batch.insert('Test', {'name': 'item'});
batch.update('Test', {'name': 'new_item'}, where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: ['item']);
batch.delete('Test', where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: ['item']);
results = await batch.commit();
```

I suggest you use [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive). It is fast and can work well with the `build` method of flutter.

> Hive greatly outperforms SQLite and SharedPreferences when it comes to
> writing or deleting.